# Destructuring in function parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Lets assume we have such function:

```
const func = (a, b, {c: {d}}) => {console.dir(c)}
```

How is this function should be called and what structure of 3rd parameter?
I tried a lot of variations, but always got an error: `Cannot destructure property`d`of 'undefined' or 'null'.`

Thanks!

Comment: `func("a", "b", { c: { d: "d" } });`

Comment: Please show us the variations you tried.

Comment: You might want to paste that code into a transpiler (e.g. http://babeljs.io/repl/) to see the ES5 version of what it does

Comment: Btw, did you mean `console.dir(d)`? There is no `c` variable declared in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const func = (a, b, {c: {d}}) => {console.dir(d)}
func(null, null, {c: {d: document.location}});
```

This function has to be called with object that has key `c`, which has object with key `d` as value:

```
func(a, b, {c: {d: document.location }})
```

[`console.dir()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir) takes any JS object as parameter.

`{ c: {d}}` is a syntax called object destructuring and its purpose in this context is unpacking fields from objects passed as function parameter.

`{d}` is shorter syntax for object with key `d` and value of variable `d` (`{d: d}`).

To unpack variable `d` from object under key `c`, that object have to have that key initialized! But when you further destructurize the object passed as argument, you don't have that object as a variable in the scope.

In example you have provided, you will not be able to access object `c`, as it has been destructurized and only object `d` is available. Either you have mistake in your code or you need something like Anurat Chapanond has posted.

Comment: That's right. I just realize that in my answer console.dir(c) accesses variable c through closure. It is more likely that DefLee intends to call console.dir(d) instead.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond this console.log(c) actually confused me a little bit. For some reasons I thought that destructuring  will take property "c" as function parameter too (because it takes whole object as 3rd parameter)

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk I would like to upvote your answer, but can't because of my reputation ) Thanks for your answer. One more question for clarification: when we are specifying "{c: {d}}" in function parameters declaration in other words we want to take property "d" and store its content into function variable "d"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example.

```
const func = (a, b, {c: {d}}) => {console.dir(c)},
    c = { d: 'hello' }

func(1, 2, { c })
```

I define c as an object with a property d which is a string 'hello'.

when func is called, the third parameter I pass to the function is an object with a property c.

{ c } is a shorthand for { c: c }

Comment: Your answer is valid too. But I was interesting in getting "c" from parameters and not from outer scope. Now I understand that it's not possible to do in the way I did

Comment: I agree. You can also get c from parameters if you declare your function parameter as func = (a, b, { c }) => {console.dir(c)}